Designing Toolbar
I've to design this toolbar but no matter how hard I tried, I couldn't succeed.
How can I add the widgets correctly to toolbar? Is there a library I should use?

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/market_logo"
            >

        </ImageView>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

It must be same
When I added the icon to toolbar I couldn't set the position
